# Quotes within quotes within quotes

Tags: php

I'm using a bootstrap 3 pop over, inside the popover is a form.

I'm having trouble with quotes, it's not liking '"''"' (quotes within quotes within quotes).

What is a good way around this?

```
isset(Auth::user()->name) ? '<span id="username" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="
                <form id='change-password'>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <input name='old-password' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Old Password'>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <input name='new-password' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='New Password'>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <input name='confirm-password' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Confirm Password'>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'><i class='icon-ok-sign icon-large'></i> Save</button>
                    </div>
                </form>" data-original-title="" title="Change Password">'.Auth::user()->name.'</span>':  ''
```

Comment: Don't use ternary for massive amounts of content. Don't use strings for massive amounts of content. Use an `if ()` statement and put the main content between `?>` and `<?php`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use double quotes all the time.  You can use single quotes (') within another set of quotes.  This is the most common way to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 0):

Use the opposite one  e.g

```
"<p> 'Hello'</p>"
```

or

```
'<p> "hello" </p>'
```